# Deleting entire row whose column contains a 0, Excel 2007 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATE:

Alright, so i used the following code and it does what i need it to do, i.e check if the value is 0 and if its is, then delete the entire row. However i want to do this to multiple worksheets inside one workbook, one at a time. What the following code is doing is that it removes the zeros only from the current spreadsheet which is active by default when you open excel through the VBA script. here the working zero removal code:

```
Dim wsDCCTabA As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsTempGtoS As Excel.Worksheet

Set wsDCCTabA = wbDCC.Worksheets("Login")
Set wsTempGtoS = wbCalc.Worksheets("All_TemporaryDifferences")

Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
LastRow = wsTempGtoS.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(n, 5).Value = 0 Then
    Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
```

What am i doing wrong? when i do the same thing for another worksheet inside the same workbook it doesnt do anything. I am using the following code to remove zeros from anohter worksheet:

```
Set wsPermGtoS = wbCalc.Worksheets("All_PermanentDifferences")
'delete rows with 0 description  
Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
LastRow = wsPermGtoS.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(n, 5).Value = 0 Then
    Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
```

Any thoughts? or another way of doing the same thing?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I want to delete all the rows which have a zero in a particular column. I am using the following code but nothing seems to happen:

```
 CurrRow = (Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)
 For Count = StartRow To CurrRow
     If wsDCCTabA.Range("E" & Count).Value = "0" Then
         wsDCCTabA.Rows(Count).Delete
     End If
 Next
```

`StartRow` contains the starting row value
`CurrRow` contains the row value of the last used row

Comment: I presume you mean VBA (inside Excel) rather than `vbscript`. Question re-tagged accordingly

Comment: Try debugging line by line (F8) and checking the value of each variable.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
Sub DelSomeRows()

    Dim colNo As Long:      colNo = 5             ' hardcoded to look in col 5
    Dim ws    As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet  ' on the active sheet

    Dim rgCol As Range
    Set rgCol = ws.Columns(colNo)                          ' full col range (huge)
    Set rgCol = Application.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rgCol) ' shrink to nec size
    Dim rgZeroCells As Range ' range to hold all the "0" cells (union of disjoint cells)
    Dim rgCell      As Range ' single cell to iterate
    For Each rgCell In rgCol.Cells
        If Not IsError(rgCell) Then
            If rgCell.Value = "0" Then
                If rgZeroCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rgZeroCells = rgCell ' found 1st one, assign
                Else
                    Set rgZeroCells = Union(rgZeroCells, rgCell) ' found another, append
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rgCell
    If Not rgZeroCells Is Nothing Then
        rgZeroCells.EntireRow.Delete ' deletes all the target rows at once
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: gives me an error that method not found for Application.Intersect.
Are you sure this is compatible in excel 2007?

Comment: I used 2010, but 2007 should have an intersect method - try changing to plain "Intersect" instead of Application.Intersect. (Also - make sure the ranges actually intersect - e.g. if col 5 was empty this would cause a runtime error - by design).

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete a row, u need to minus the "Count" variable

```
CurrRow = (Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)
For Count = StartRow To CurrRow
    If wsDCCTabA.Range("E" & Count).Value = "0" Then
        wsDCCTabA.Rows(Count).Delete
        ' Add this line:
        Count = Count - 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You could also reverse loop your count from bottom to top if you want to prevent having to reset your count by -1 after deleting a row.

Comment: Yes, you can actually use Do While ... Loop as well

Answer (score 0):

I got it. For future reference, i used

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All_temporaryDifferences").Activate
```

and

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All_Permanentdifferences").Activate
```

Comment: It's great that you shared your fix but this isn't really a good answer. It obscures your actual problem. The real answer is to specify which worksheet when using `Range()` or `Cells()` (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All_temporaryDifferences").Activate`. In fact if the `ActiveWorkbook` is different from `wbCalc` you would get an error.

Your real problem is that you are using an unqualified reference to `Cells(n, 5).Value`. Unqualified means that you aren't specifying which sheet to use so it defaults to the active sheet. That may work sometimes but it is poor code. In your case it didn't work.

Instead you should always use qualified references. `wsTempGtoS.Cells(n, 5).Value` is a qualified reference. `wsTempGtoS` specifies which worksheet you want so VBA is not left guessing.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
LastRow = wsTempGtoS.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If wsTempGtoS.Cells(n, 5).Value = 0 Then
        wsTempGtoS.Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

This: `CurrRow = (Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)` is also an unqualified reference. Instead it should be `CurrRow = wsDCCTabA.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row`.